# Generating annotated ( @NamedPLSQLStoredFunctionQuery / @NamedPLSQLStoredProcedureQuery) queries

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpa-annotations

**Environment**
- JavaSE 6, Oracle 11, WebSphere 7, eclipseLink 2.5.2 / 2.6.0

**Use Case**

In our project we use (call from Java) lot of PL/SQL procedures, and functions.
We would like to generate annotated queries like

```
@NamedPLSQLStoredFunctionQuery(name = "convertToString", functionName = "my_schema.my_package.convert_to_string", parameters = { @PLSQLParameter(name = "p_boolean", databaseType = "BOOLEAN") }, returnParameter = @PLSQLParameter(name = "RESULT", databaseType = "VARCHAR_TYPE"))
```

from database metadata, i.e. procedure/function spec.

**Question**

Is there any support from eclipseLink or any 3rd party library generating this?

Regards
Jan

Comment: In JPA a stored procedure is defined via @NamedStoredProcedureQuery not what you quote there

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no tools that generate JPA/EclipseLink query annotations from stored procedures that exist in the database.  I don't think it would be feasible to write one that could determine and interpret what all the stored procedure/functions that might exist in the database are for and would be desired in a JPA persistence unit.